# the type must implement the inherited abstract method Reducer.reduce(Object, Iterator, OutputCollector, Reporter)

Tags: mapper

I am new to Hadoop, and this is my first Hadoop program.

I am trying to create a Mapper class called WordMapper, but it throws be the below error.

The type WordMapper must implement the inherited abstract method Mapper.map(Object, Object, OutputCollector, Reporter)

```
public class WordMapper extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper 
{
    public void map(WritableComparable key, Writable values, OutputCollector output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException 
    {
        String line=values.toString();
        StringTokenizer tok=new StringTokenizer(line);
        while(tok.hasMoreTokens())
        {
            String t=tok.nextToken();
            output.collect(new Text(t), new IntWritable(1));
        }

    }

}
```

Can someone please tell me where i am going wrong and suggest to overcome the problem

Answer (score 2):

try to fulfill your Mapper parameter like this:

```
public class WCMapper extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>

public void map(LongWritable key, Text values, OutputCollector output, Reporter reporter)
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided any of the type parameters. `Mapper` is a generic interface; it's parameterized with type parameters for the input and output key and value types. Fill in `K1`, `V1`, `K2`, and `V2` in the following code with the types you need:

```
public class WordMapper extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<K1, V1, K2, V2> {
    public void map(K1 key,
                    V1 value,
                    OutputCollector<K2, V2> output,
                    Reporter reporter)
            throws IOException {
        whatever();
    }
}
```